# Magento1 Admin Order create shipping method missing

Tags: magento-1.9, php, admin, orders, shipping-methods

Magento 1, while **creating an order from the admin shipping method is disappear** I don’t know how. Before few days it was there. Under shipping method **“Get shipping methods and rates”** link was there but now it’s missing.

We have checked our demo environment its showing there. Shipping setting correct on both the website. But no shipping method on Live website.

Anyone please let me know what’s the issue?

> Live Screenshot:

[image]

> Staging Screenshot:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please compare your shipping settings with live/staging sites will get more idea. Or disable any shipping extension that you added before it was showing. Check the error log also.

Comment: @DineshRajput I did all but no changes. both the webiste are same